# Отличие прототипного наследования от обычного наследования

Tags: javascript, ооп, наследование, прототипное-наследование

Прочитал [Прототипное наследование](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype-inheritance), [F.prototype](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-prototype) и [Встроенные прототипы](https://learn.javascript.ru/native-prototypes)

Возник вопрос: "Чем прототипное наследование отличается от обычного"?

К примеру

```js
let testVariable = new testConstructor();
```

Тогда если `let testVariable = new testConstructor();`, то с одной стороны `testVariable` наследуется от `testConstructor` (т. к. создана с помощью оператора `new testConstructor();`), а с другой стороны `testVariable.__proto__=testConstructor.prototype` (опять же потому что создана с помощью оператора `new`), т. е. `testVariable` прототипно наследуется от `testConstructor.prototype`. В чем отличие прототипного наследования от обычного?

Comment: Почитайте про [переопределение методов](https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance), возможно это часть ответа.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под «обычным» наследованием?

Comment: @andreymal наследование без свойства _proto_.

Comment: Какое именно «наследование без свойства _proto_» вы имеете в виду? Покажите пример, что ли

Comment: @andreymal я уточнил вопрос.